# Overlaying in Beamer -- Setting the text on each overlay to be in the same spot when each overlay has some different text

Tags: beamer, spacing, itemize, overlays

I am trying to create a slide in beamer that has four overlays. There are four sections to the slide. On each overlay, each subsequent section of the slide appears and along with additional information about it. The additional information then disappears on the subsequent overlay but the main information remains.

My question is for the information from the first overlay. How can I ensure that it appears int he same spot each time? It might not by default simply based on the amount of text in the overlay. Beamer then adjusts the spacing.

The line "Bullet 1: text" I want to appear in the same spot in each overlay. I'm just taking a guess and doing trial by error to set the spacing. Is there a way though that I wouldn't need to do trial by error?

```
\documentclass[professionalfont]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{}

\frame
{
\frametitle{Slide Title}
\only<1>{
\vspace{-2.6cm}
\textbf{Bullet 1:} text
\begin{itemize}
\item Clarification
\end{itemize}
}

\only<2>{
\vspace{-1.1cm}
Bullet 1: text

\vspace{0.65cm}
\textbf{Bullet 2:} text
\begin{itemize}
\item Clarification1
\item Clarification2
\item Clarification3
\end{itemize}
}

\only<3>{
\vspace{-0.7cm}
Bullet 1: text

\vspace{0.65cm}
Bullet 2: text

\vspace{0.65cm}
\textbf{Bullet 3:} text
\begin{itemize}
\vspace{0.05cm}
\item Clarification1
\item Clarification2
\end{itemize}
}

\only<4>{
Bullet 1: text

\pause
\vspace{0.65cm}
Bullet 2: text

\pause
\vspace{0.65cm}
Bullet 3: text

\pause
\vspace{0.65cm}
\textbf{Bullet 4:} text
\begin{itemize}
\item Clarification1
\item Clarification2
\end{itemize}
}
}

\end{document}
```

I

Comment: Sounds like you need either an overlayarea or overprint environment.  You can read about these in the excellent beamer manual.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  What is this manual to which you refer?